# MySQL Error 1064 NOT NULL DEFAULT

Tags: mysql

I am experiencing following problem with my MYSQL query:

> Error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(14) NOT NULL, station varchar(4) NOT NULL default '', PRIMARY KEY (stati' at line 2

The query is as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE metars (
    timestamp timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
    station varchar(4) NOT NULL default '',
    PRIMARY KEY  (station),
    UNIQUE KEY station (station)
);
```

Thank you very much in advance for helping me with understanding this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused by malicious `(14)` fraction.

In mysql the `timestamp` type is not parameterized.

So the correct definition for the first column would be

```
timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
```

Answer (score 0):

why are you using 14? this worked for me.

```
CREATE TABLE metars (  
  timestamp timestamp NOT NULL,
  station varchar(4) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (station),
 UNIQUE KEY station (station)
 );
```